# Comparing charAt(x) to String array = letter [y]

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a piece of code that produces a letter frequency using arrays. I am getting a bit stuck on how to compare a letter in a string to a letter in an array. my basic pseudo code is as follows.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class test {
    public static void main (String[]args){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print ("Please enter a sentence: ");
        String str = sc.nextLine();

        String [] let = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
        Float [] freq = new Float [25];



        int x,a = 0,b = 0, strCount = 0;
        String str1;

        str1 = str.replaceAll(" ", "");

        for (x = 0; x < str1.length(); x++)
        {
            strCount++;
        }
        System.out.println("The number of Characters in the string is :" + strCount);
        System.out.println();
```

And now I'm stuck on how to compare the str1 to the let array. I have tried the following but it has a problem with the comparing.

```
    while (b < strCount)
    {
        while (a < let.length)
        {
            if (let[a] == str1.charAt(b))
            {
                freq[a] = freq[a]++ ;
            }
            if(let[a] != str1.charAt(b))
            {
                a = a++;
            }
        }
        b = b++;
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Also please ignore how messy the code is at the moment I'll worry about clearing it up once I work out where I'm going with comparing as this is just to test ideas on how to make the code work the way I want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I see a number of other issues but the one you're asking about is simple enough.

```
if (let[a].charAt(0) == str1.charAt(b)) // <-- one letter
{
    freq[a]++ ;
}
else
{
    a++;
}
```

Also, `strCount = str1.length();` with no need for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to get rid of the risk of eternal loops by replacing your while loops with 
    for
loops.
Also,
    a = a++;
is incorrect, while
    a++;
or
    a = a+1;
is correct.
Fix those two, and you will have fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let me address some of the problems that seem to stand out. First of all, you might want to enlarge your `Float[]` since it has a size of **25** and there are **26** letters in the alphabet, meaning you would want to do `Float[] freq = new Float[26]`instead. Also, you use `str.replaceAll()`, but `str.replace()` will suffice - they both replace all matches in the string.

To count the number of occurrences, you may want to use `str.charAt(index)` or break it up into a char array (`str.toCharArray()`) to compare the character with the values stored in the array. Since they are all single characters, you might also want to store the values as the primitive `char` instead of as a `String`.

The two `while` loops are completely unnecessary, as it can be done with the one `for`loop. Also, use `str.length()` instead of creating your own variable and using a `for` loop to increment `strCount`, especially when you specify to loop through it `str.length()` times...

Comment: When declaring an array at uni we were told that it is 25 because it also counts 0 as part of the array meaning 25 + the 0 entry on the array would make 26? So the array would look something like 0 = a, 1 = b... y = 24, z = 25

Thank you for the rest of the advice though as it is helpful. I didn't think about just using a char array. I also realise that the while loops are not needed.

Comment: The array should have a length of 26, with valid indexes from 0-25. However, the size should still be initialized as 26, since Java makes the valid indexes from 0-25 - otherwise freq[25] will give you a NullPointerException.